# Symmetrisation of system of conservation laws

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have a system
$$\partial_t \rho +\nabla_x\cdot \upsilon(\rho)=0,$$
where $x\in \Bbb R^3$, $\rho:(t,x)\to \Bbb R^5$, $\upsilon: \Bbb R^5\to \Bbb R^3$.

Suppose also that there exists a convex function $\sigma (\rho)$ and a function $\tau (\rho)$ such that 
$$\partial_t \sigma(\rho) +\nabla_x\cdot \tau(\rho)\le0$$
in the sense of distributions.

I'd like to know if there's something useful that I can pull of this existence of $\sigma$ and $\tau$. The books I found work with the case $x\in \Bbb R$ and not $\Bbb R^3$; moreover, they suppose that this inequality holds for all pairs  "entropy/entropy flux", and not for just one pair. Is it possible to prove that my system is hyperbolic (or symmetrically hyperbolic)? Just a reference would be nice.

I'll be glad to hear all suggestions.